# Orika nested properties flattening

Tags: java, nested, flatten, orika

I need a help with flattening n-levels deep structure to single level object properties. The convention is to use underscore character (level1_level2_level3). I'm using orika (http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html)

Eg.

```
Variable1.Property1.Property2.Property3
```

where Property1 is Set, Property2 is class and Property3 is String.

My needed mapping in orika can be achieved using this setting:

```
.field("Property1{Property2.Property3}", "Property1_Property2_Property3")
```

The problem is that I need generic solution that can be n-levels deep. If type is list/collection, I would take only first element (if list/collection is not empty).

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Class1 {

String property1;
Set<Class2> property2;

}

Class2 {

String property3;
Class3 property4;

}

Class3 {

String property5;    

}



MapHere {

String property1;
String property2_property3;
String property2_property4_property5;

}
```

Update:

Here is implementation of FlattenClassMapBuilder in case somebody needs it: http://pastie.org/9324242

And also, mapping by package:

```
    String aPrefix = "com.something.domain";
    String bPrefix = "com.something.dto";

    //----------------------
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(aPrefix, new SubTypesScanner(false));
    //uzmi sve klase iz paketa koji je dat u aPrefix putanji (recimo "com.nesto.nesto1")
    Set<Class<?>> aClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    reflections = new Reflections(bPrefix, new SubTypesScanner(false));
    //uzmi sve klase iz paketa koji je dat u bPrefix putanji (recimo "com.nesto.nesto2")
    Set<Class<?>> bClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    for(Class<?> aClass : aClasses)
    {
        for(Class<?> bClass : bClasses)
        {
            if(aClass.getSimpleName().equals(bClass.getSimpleName()))
            {
                //za sve klase iz aPrefix-a cije se ime poklapa sa klasom iz bPrefix-a
                mapperFactory.classMap(aClass, bClass).byDefault().register();
            }
        }
    }
    //------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact Orika can handle this, but you should provide this automatic mapping policy by providing an implementation for [DefaultFieldMapper](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/core/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/DefaultFieldMapper.java)

In the Orika source code / tests, there is some examples.

Comment: I tried this approach, but I came to step where i need to map List<> property (in my case Property1), but what I need in fact is Property1.Property2.Property3 - that is nested property of this one.

Comment: Or you can even use provide your own ClassMapBuilder/Factory, override byDefault method to impelment your policy. For example when you face List<->PropertX you can register a converter by id. Do some cases anually using converters (for List<->PropertyX) once the algo is clear in your mind you can automate it (DefaultFieldMapper / custom ClassMapBuilder). Orika provide a lot of extension point it depends on each case/need which one to pick.

Comment: do you have any sample of this? Here is a mapping that I want to achieve: (edited original question)

Comment: Here is an example that try to do case insensitive mapping https://gist.github.com/elaatifi/7009879

Comment: I downloaded the code, but do you know how to continue mapping when I encounter nested property?

Comment: There is in fact an experimental ClassMapBuilder that address the same issue as yours ScoringClassMapBuilder (but taking approximative approach) you can try to use it and then you can look at to understand  how it works

Comment: Thanks for this. I think that I'll find how to do It. One more question - do you know how to map complete package (namespace) one to the other, since I have the objects with same name in different packages.

Comment: You can use classpath scanning to look for which classes do you want to map. https://code.google.com/p/reflections/ or Spring provide also utils to classpath scaning

Comment: Thanks for all help. I created my implementation and it's working (sort of). I don't know why this mapping is not giving me desired results: class1{class2.class3{class4{class5.name}}}  ---> should this map to Set<class1>.class2.List<class3>.List<class4>.class5.name ? I have an error saying that getClass3 is not found in class1